# JavaScript error on embedded Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, javascript, regedit, widgets

I have a wallboard setup to display statistics in the office, however the widget that uses embedded Internet Explorer keeps coming up with a JavaScript error.

[image]

The error can be closed without causing problems but it's irritating as it keeps coming back every so often around 2-3 times a day, and when it does it stops anyone from viewing statistics till it's closed by remotely accessing the wallboard.
In regular Internet Explorer this can be easily stopped by unticking the option below.

[image]

My question is how to disable this script error pop-up in the Internet Explorer that's embedded into my widget?

**Edit: Response to answer from harrymc**

I have now edited these settings using regedit as per harrymc's instructions, however the error still pops up.

Comment: Are you saying the wallboard doesn't give you access to the Internet Settings? Also, the JS error is fairly easy to fix. It is missing a check in the code to cope with a null or undefined variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the code, it's all built in so that all I can change is basic settings. I can change browser settings on the wallboard but the embedded IE seems to use separate settings

Comment: can you edit the registry of the machine? You may be able to set the IE control panel option via the registry?

Comment: I can edit the registry though I'm unsure which is the correct option in regedit (there's a lot for IE) and once I find it what do I change it to?

Comment: Why don't you just correct the JavaScript to resolve the error?

Comment: As an aside: note that though you're writing *"The error can be closed without causing problems"*, it seems there's actually [quite a bit of JavaScript](https://daviker.whccs.com/reports/js/rm.ui.js) not being executed after the error occurs. Also, if one day that remote script changes, things can fail differently. I guess a support ticket to the supplier is the best option, but of course that is not what you're asking about.

Comment: Probably its the debugger that gives the error, try disable.

Comment: Any updates? Did you try any of my suggestions?

Comment: Hi Arjan, no sorry I didn't give them a try, harrymc's answer seems to have done the trick, I was just waiting to see if it was a permanent fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can edit the registry, the following article lists many IE settings :
[How to Customize Virtual Internet Explorer Settings](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-customize-virtual-internet-explorer-settings).

To disable "Display a Notification about Every Script Error", use the following .reg file :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Error Dlg Displayed On Every Error"="no"
```

Comment: Hi harrymc, please see my response above

Comment: Never mind I think I worked it out now. the registry you were on about wasn't on the wallboard but it was on my pc, so I exported it and copied it over, just have to wait and see if the error comes back now

Comment: Sigh, the error still comes up even with the registry changed

Comment: You might need to reboot.

Comment: I restarted the software, do you mean the whole wallboard pc?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Fully restarted now so I'll keep a eye out for the error re-appearing

Comment: No errors yet, still going to keep monitoring though as it has occasionally been known to go away for a day then come back.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, rather than trying to hide the error, you might be able to avoid it altogether (or point your supplier to this post to fix their JavaScript):

- Maybe the server returns no value at all for the "opened tabs" in the JavaScript below; **try to change the widget's tabs settings** to force the server to set some value. If you cannot do this in the wallboard, then try in a regular browser, hoping such would save the settings to the server.

When this doesn't help, try the following in a "regular" Internet Explorer browser:

- Maybe the domain of the URL you're using is different from the one from which the script is loaded (or: the URL from which the widget loads its HTML or data), making IE feel it's handling a third-party cookie. So: **see what allowing third-party cookies gets you**. See Microsoft's [Block, enable, or allow cookies](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/block-enable-or-allow-cookies).
- Maybe setting or reading cookies in JavaScript needs some additional rights. So: **see if adding `daviker.whccs.com` to the trusted sites helps**, to allow it to do a bit more? See Microsoft's [Security zones: adding or removing websites](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-zones-adding-removing-websites#1TC=windows-7).
- Maybe the server has already set a cookie with the same name, but marked it as [HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly), making it inaccessible from JavaScript. **Try deleting any existing "active-tabs" cookie**.

Background:

The error on line 1546 of [the script](https://daviker.whccs.com/reports/js/rm.ui.js) is related to a specific cookie not being available to that script, right after the very same script tried to set/change that cookie itself (on line 1541, where its value might actually be `undefined` as line 1533 fails to check for that):

```js
1527    restoreTabsFromTheServer: function()
1528    {
1529        $.post("xrm_ui?get=getTabs", {}, function(responce) {
1530
1531            reportTabs.tabCaptions = responce.reportPages;
1532
                // Next line only checks for an empty "openedtabs", not for
                // an undefined or null value; bad coding...
1533            if (responce.openedtabs == '')
1534            {
1535                $.cookie("active-tabs", '');
1536                reportTabs.tabidSelected = undefined;
1537                reportTabs.tabindexSelected = undefined;
                    // Next line would exit the function if we had an empty
                    // result, but not if it is undefined or null
1538                return false;
1539            }
1540
                // Next line: NO ERROR WHILE WRITING, but the new value could
                // be undefined, which might even clear an existing cookie?
1541            $.cookie("active-tabs", responce.openedtabs);
1542            reportTabs.tabidSelected = responce.tabidselected;
1543            reportTabs.tabindexSelected = responce.tabindexselected;
1544
1545            // restore tabs
                // Next line: NO RESULT WHEN READING
1546            var arr = $.cookie("active-tabs").split(',');
1547            ...
```

So, it seems that the embedded IE is ignoring the JavaScript setting that cookie, or the JavaScript sets the cookie to be undefined. And then when trying to read back its value it's empty<sup>†</sup>.

I don't know if the embedded IE component uses the "regular" IE browser *settings* for cookies. But I have surely seen embedded IE components *share* cookies with the IE browser. (Like when clicking links in Excel when IE is not the default browser, [IE cookies are still used for some discovery](https://superuser.com/questions/444984/excel-hyperlink-not-redirecting-properly-bug/445431#445431).) So, maybe changing the settings in the "regular" IE browser will allow JavaScript to set this cookie in the embedded component.

---

<sup>†</sup> Alternatively, maybe the value that is received from the server in line 1529 is not a valid value, making the writing or reading fail. Like [commas are not allowed in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387340/is-comma-a-valid-character-in-cookie-value), so the `.split(',')` looks suspicious. But then: we don't even know which jQuery plugin is used for `$.cookie`, so we'd need much more detail to figure out if it is using some encoding.

Comment: I wish i could aware bonus points for trying to solve the problem instead of a symptom ( i.e. not loading the script or just ignoring the error).

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound. On the other hand, maybe my answer is far too specific for a Stack Exchange Q&A site (as for the chance that a future visitor will have the same problem)...

Comment: Your answer wasn't the one that I used but it was a lot better :p

Comment: Ah, when not having provided any credentials, a GET to [`xrm_ui?get=getTabs`](https://daviker.whccs.com/reports/xrm_ui?get=getTabs) yields `null` rather than an empty string like for the other values: `{"openedtabs": null, "tabindexselected": "", "tabidselected": ""}`. Maybe the same happens when the script executes the POST, presumably with a proper authenticated session.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing a similar case to this with Windows 11, you may experience the frustration that the ability to untick "Display a notification about every script error" is not available in Internet Options any more.  The excellent solution from harrymc to modify this setting via the Registry also seems to be ignored by Internet Explorer now.

If you are simply trying to avoid an annoying prompt from a given app that is calling a particular URL, one potential solution is to prevent scripts running on that website altogether (if this doesn't break functionality for your app).  The simpliest way to achieve this is as follows:

- Press Start, type "Internet Options" and press Enter. [image: Internet Options search match in the start menu]
- Under the Security tab, click "Restricted sites" and then click "Sites". Under the Security tab within Internet Options, there is a zone labelled Restricted Sites which looks like a no entry sign.  Click that and then click the Sites button underneath[image: Under the Security tab within Internet Options, there is a zone labelled Restricted Sites which looks like a no entry sign. Click that and then click the Sites button underneath]
- Enter the website you wish to disable scripts for and click "Add". Under the Add this website to the zone text box, type the website you wish to add (usually without any path suffix) and click Add.  For the case within this article, the website may be https://daviker.whccs.com  You have the ability to select a website you previously added and click Remove to further configure this zone.[image: Under the Add this website to the zone text box, type the website you wish to add (usually without any path suffix) and click Add. For the case within this article, the website may be https://daviker.whccs.com You have the ability to select a website you previously added and click Remove to further configure this zone.]

Click Close and then OK.