# How to prevent Excel from making unauthorized pre-request to links in the sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The formula is as follows

`=HYPERLINK(ALS.NB(VERT.ZOEKEN([@Module];Modules_tbl;2;ONWAAR);"")&[@IssueNr]; [@IssueNr])`

[image: gif]

After some digging it looks like it has to do with sessions.

How can I prevent Excel from making these unauthorized (no session) requests?

Comment: Opens what previous URL. Just a tip: the title of the question is not the question, or the problem statement. Please EDIT your question to make it more clear and complete.

Comment: @music2myear the previous url I have opened

Comment: Check if the upvote 11 reply is helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/444984/excel-hyperlink-not-redirecting-properly-bug/445431

Comment: @karel yes, please see the very last sentence of my question.

Comment: @karel It's the same problem, however it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a little piece of code to fix it and also added a hosted version of it for everyone to use.

https://github.com/thomasmoors/excel-link-fixer

http://excel.gratisapi.nl/?url=

Answer (score 1):

The hyperlink assigned to the corresponding IssueURL is most likely your culprit.

The URL you are seeing in the screenshot is a `Comment`, not the actual URL. Of course, it should also turn out that the assigned URL matches the one in the `Comment` but for a variety of reasons, such things can change.

The idea would be to investigate the problem by right-clicking random IssueURL column cells and then choosing `Edit Hyperlink` to see if the hyperlinks match. Naturally, examine the same for ANY cell you've already identified as having this problem.

As proof this is the issue, notice that the URL it sends you to seems to be https://etc.../396. Clearly, it won't match... and you will surely find plenty of others. This is an Excel level problem that won't be a simple repair. Not a deep problem, and caused by Excel mishandling ambiguous orders to Sort or a few other such commands that can separate things like Objects and the cells they are assigned to. After happening and saving, there's no Undo-ing, so no simple solution.

In your case, there may be a fairly easy solution though. The URL's look to be a block of URL text with a variable portion at the very end that happens to be the value in the IssuesNR column. So you could create a string for tha URL string and append the Issues NR value to the end. Then your created `HYPERLINK()` would avoid the IssuesURL column and its corrupted information altogether:

```
=HYPERLINK(ALS.NB(VERT.ZOEKEN([@Module];Modules_tbl;2;ONWAAR);"")),"")&"https://git.proautnorm.com/configurators/profielnorm/configurator/-/issues/"&IssueNR,IssueNR)
```

which works for me. (With English Excel functions:  I may have messed up changing back to yours, but think I got it right.)

Another alternative, if you are a little skilled with VBA would be to write a macro that went down the table changing the URL's assigned to the IssuesURL column cells to the same thing the above formula would assign. Also fast and easy and would achieve the same result.

Naturally, both assume the URL's should be the simple beginning string plus the variable values from the IssueNR cells.